# Cordova polluted logs with persistent.js add()

Tags: cordova, logging

I am using the latest phonegap/cordova version 2.1. and my log in Eclipse logcat  get polluted with code when i do
    var allItems = Item.all();

```
allItems.list(null, function (results) {
    results.forEach(function (r) {
        console.log(r.id+ " " + r.lat + " " + r.long + " " + r.state);
    });
});
```

I get a output like (for 100s of lines)

```
10-29 10:56:13.270: I/Web Console(5961):     } function (value) {
10-29 10:56:13.270: I/Web Console(5961):         if (value === undefined) {
10-29 10:56:13.270: I/Web Console(5961):             return getterCallback();
10-29 10:56:13.270: I/Web Console(5961):         } else {
10-29 10:56:13.270: I/Web Console(5961):             setterCallback(value);
10-29 10:56:13.270: I/Web Console(5961):             return scope;
10-29 10:56:13.270: I/Web Console(5961):         }
10-29 10:56:13.270: I/Web Console(5961):     } function (value) {
10-29 10:56:13.270: I/Web Console(5961):         if (value === undefined) {
10-29 10:56:13.270: I/Web Console(5961):             return getterCallback();
10-29 10:56:13.270: I/Web Console(5961):         } else {
10-29 10:56:13.270: I/Web Console(5961):             setterCallback(value);
10-29 10:56:13.270: I/Web Console(5961):             return scope;
10-29 10:56:13.270: I/Web Console(5961):         }
10-29 10:56:13.270: I/Web Console(5961):     } function (value) {
10-29 10:56:13.270: I/Web Console(5961):         if (value === undefined) {
10-29 10:56:13.270: I/Web Console(5961):             return getterCallback();
10-29 10:56:13.270: I/Web Console(5961):         } else {
10-29 10:56:13.270: I/Web Console(5961):             setterCallback(value);
10-29 10:56:13.270: I/Web Console(5961):             return scope;
10-29 10:56:13.270: I/Web Console(5961):         }
10-29 10:56:13.270: I/Web Console(5961):     } at :1149822901
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution was, that the objects were empty and so returned a function which was displayed, this was caused by a bug in persistance.js: see [persistence.js add() function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126293/persistence-js-add-function-not-working)