# persistence.js add() function not working

Tags: javascript, persistence

I have tried to save an object to database:

```
Item = persistence.define('Item', {
imageUrl: "TEXT",
})
```

this is working,the imageUrl is set correctly:

```
var c = new Item({imageUrl: "a"});
```

this is not working, imageUrl is empty in the db

```
var c = new Item();
c.imageUrl = "a";
```

this is working:

```
var c = new Item();
c._data.imageUrl = "a";
```

Seems like a bug.

Comment: What browser are you running this in?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the reason, If you are using jquery then you have to use:
e. g.

```
obj.name(newValue)
```

to set and

```
obj.name()
```

to get attributs.

Can you please tell me where the documentation for such cases can be found?
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/persistencejs/zph_wV1sEic